# equalTo is not working for Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have a problem with Firebase; I'm trying to retrieve all my posts, in javascript, that in the correct language, they are "published" and ordered by published date.

My Firebase database is like this:

```
{
posts:
  uuid:
    images: object
    options: 
      en: 
        status: "Published"
        date: "Thu Feb 18 2016 16:49:58 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"
      es: 
        status: "Draft"
}
```

and every object is similar.

The query I have tried for this is:

```
fireBase.child('posts').orderByChild('en/status').equalTo('Published').once('value', function( snapshot ){ 
  console.log( snapshot.val() ); 
});
```

But the snapshot is *null*. Even if I have a status **Published** in more than one post.

So my first problem is that I can't even get my posts with this query nor other queries I have tried.

And my second issue is that I don't get how I can order by "en/date" after I have requested the status to be published, If I try to add another .orderByChild() it say that I can only have one.

Thank's a lot for your help.

Comment: I think you are missing a level - how about   /options/en/status. What you posted would work if the en: and es: were children of uuid.

Comment: Thanks @Jay it worked! As I was able to say for example orderByChild('status') without specifying **options** or **en** I though I was able to do the same for 'en/status'.

Comment: Great! I will make it an answer since it solved the question. If that's ok, please accept it as it's something a lot of people overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a level - how about /options/en/status.

What you posted would work if the en: and es: were children of uuid.